# Custom Calendar - de-reference a null object - PRODUCTION

Tags: apex, null-pointer, public-calendar

I'm running into an interesting issue, in production.
I'm building a custom calendar, which the code was taken from open source [Ross Heuss](http://developer.force.com/codeshare/projectpage?id=a0630000002ahp6AAA).
I've made some tweaks and such, in sandbox it works perfectly, but in production, I get an error, only if you proceed past February.

```
Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!next}' in page calendarpage: Class.eventItem.<init>: line 29, column 1
Class.Month.setEvents: line 58, column 1
Class.repeatCon.setMonth: line 52, column 1
Class.repeatCon.addMonth: line 58, column 1
Class.repeatCon.next: line 4, column 1
```

From what I understand (I think) is that the datetime is returning NULL for some reason, so is crashes. But its weird that it will grab all events from Jan and Feb.

I hope you all can help!

evenItem.cls

```
   public class eventItem {
        public Event ev;
        public String formatedDate; 
        public String loc;
      //  public String accId;
        public String evid;
        public String name;
       public  Datetime endd;
        public eventItem(Event e) { 
            ev= e;
            // build formated date
            //9:00 AM - 1:00 PM
        //  system.debug(e.activitydatetime.format('MMM a'));
        //  system.debug(e.DurationInMinutes);
       loc = e.Location;
      // accId = e.OwnerId;
       name = e.Owner.Name;
       //evid = e.Owner.Id;
        if (e.DurationInMinutes != 1440)
        {
      endd = e.activitydatetime.addMinutes(e.DurationInMinutes); 
     }
     else 
     {
        formatedDate = ' ALL DAY '; 
     }
          //  Datetime endd = e.activitydatetime.addMinutes(e.DurationInMinutes);
            //system.debug(e.activitydatetime.format('h:mm a '));
            formatedDate = e.activitydatetime.format('h:mm a') + 
            ' - ' + endd.format('h:mm a');
            system.debug(formateddate);
        }
        public Event getEv() { return ev; }
        public String getFormatedDate() { return formatedDate; }
        public String getLoc () {return loc;}
      //  public String getId () {return accId;}
      public String getName() {return name;}
      public String getevId() {return evid;}

    }
 ----
```

Month.cls

```
global class Month {
    global List<Week> weeks; 
    public Date firstDate; // always the first of the month
    private Date upperLeft; 

    public List<Date> getValidDateRange() { 
        // return one date from the upper left, and one from the lower right
        List<Date> ret = new List<Date>();
        ret.add(upperLeft);
        ret.add(upperLeft.addDays(5*7) );
        return ret;
    }

    public String getMonthName() { 
        return DateTime.newInstance(firstDate.year(),firstdate.month(),firstdate.day()).format('MMMM');
    } 

    public String getYearName() { 
        return DateTime.newInstance(
        firstDate.year(),firstdate.month(),firstdate.day()).format('yyyy');
    } 


    public String[] getWeekdayNames() { 
        Date today = system.today().toStartOfWeek();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(today.year(),today.month(),today.day());      
        list<String> ret = new list<String>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 7;i++) { 
            ret.add( dt.formatgmt('EEEE') );
            dt= dt.addDays(1);
        } 
        return ret;
    }

    public Date getfirstDate() { return firstDate; } 

    public Month( Date value ) {
        weeks = new List<Week>();
        firstDate = value.toStartOfMonth();
        upperLeft = firstDate.toStartOfWeek();
        Date tmp = upperLeft;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Week w = new Week(i+1,tmp,value.month());   
            system.assert(w!=null); 
            this.weeks.add( w );
            tmp = tmp.addDays(7);
        }

    }

    public void setEvents(List<Event> ev) { 
        // merge these events into the proper day 
        for(Event e:ev) { 
            for(Week w:weeks) { 
                for(Day c: w.getDays() ) { 
                    if ( e.ActivityDate.isSameDay(c.theDate))  { 
                        // add this event to this calendar date
                        c.eventsToday.add(new EventItem(e));
                        // add only three events, then a More... label if there are more
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }

    public List<Week> getWeeks() { 
        system.assert(weeks!=null,'could not create weeks list');
        return weeks; 
    }


    /* 
     * helper classes to define a month in terms of week and day
     */
    public class Week {
     public List<Day> days;
     public Integer weekNumber; 
     public Date startingDate; // the date that the first of this week is on
     // so sunday of this week

     public List<Day> getDays() { return this.days; }

     public Week () { 
        days = new List<Day>();     
     }
     public Week(Integer value,Date sunday,Integer month) { 
        this();
        weekNumber = value;
        startingDate = sunday;
        Date tmp = startingDate;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            Day d = new Day( tmp,month ); 
            tmp = tmp.addDays(1);
            d.dayOfWeek = i+1;          
        //  system.debug(d);
            days.add(d);
        } 

     }
     public Integer getWeekNumber() { return this.weekNumber;}
     public Date getStartingDate() { return this.startingDate;}

    }

    public class Day {

        public Date         theDate;
        public List<EventItem>  eventsToday; // list of events for this date
        public Integer      month, dayOfWeek;
        public String       formatedDate; // for the formated time  
        public String       Location;
        public String       AccountId;

        private String      cssclass = 'calActive';

        public Date         getDate() { return theDate; }
        public Integer      getDayOfMonth() { return theDate.day(); }
        public String       getDayOfMonth2() { 
            if ( theDate.day() <= 9 ) 
                return '0'+theDate.day(); 
            return String.valueof( theDate.day()); 
        }
        public Integer getDayOfYear() { return theDate.dayOfYear(); }
        public List<EventItem>  getDayAgenda() { return eventsToday; }
        public String getLocation () {return Location;}

        public String getAccountId () {return AccountId;}
        public String       getFormatedDate() { return formatedDate; }
        public Integer      getDayNumber() { return dayOfWeek; }
        public List<EventItem>  getEventsToday() { return eventsToday; }
        public String       getCSSName() {  return cssclass; }

        public Day(Date value,Integer vmonth) { 
            theDate=value; month=vmonth;        
            formatedDate = '12 21 08';// time range..
            //9:00 AM - 1:00 PM
            eventsToday = new List<EventItem>();  
            // three possible Inactive,Today,Active  
            if ( theDate.daysBetween(System.today()) == 0 ) cssclass ='calToday';
            // define inactive, is the date in the month?
            if ( theDate.month() != month) cssclass = 'calInactive';
        }

    }

/*  static testMethod void testMe() {
        Month m = new Month( Date.newInstance(2007,11,1) );
        system.assert(m!=null); 
        List<Week> l = m.getWeeks(); 
        repeatcon r = new repeatcon(); 
        system.debug(m.getMonthName());
        Month mm = r.getMonth();
        //system.debug(mm); 
        system.debug(m.getFirstDate());
        system.debug(m.getWeekdayNames());
        for(Week w:r.getWeeks()) { 
            for(Day c:w.days) {   
                if (c.eventsToday.size() > 0 ) { 
                    String ss = String.valueOf(c.eventsToday[0].ev.ActivityDate);
                    ss = c.eventsToday[0].ev.ActivityDateTime.format('MMMM a');
                    //system.debug(ss);
                    //system.debug(c.eventsToday[0].ev);
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }


    <a href="/{v.aid}" id="{!v.ev.Id}"
    onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!v.ev.Id}').hide();"
    onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!v.ev.Id}').hide();"
    onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!v.ev.Id}','/{!v.ev.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!v.ev.Id};isAjaxRequest=1;').show();"
    onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!v.ev.Id}','/{!v.ev.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!v.ev.Id};isAjaxRequest=1;').show();"
    >{!v.ev.subject}</a>

    */
}
```

repeatCon.cls

```
public class repeatCon {

  public void next() { 
    addMonth(1);
  }

  public void prev() { 
    addMonth(-1); 
  }

  public repeatCon() {

   Date d = system.today();  // default to today 
   Integer mo = d.month(); 
   String m_param = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('mo');
   String y_param = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('yr');

   // allow a month to be passed in on the url as mo=10
   if (m_param != null) { 
        Integer mi = Integer.valueOf(m_param); 
        if (mi > 0 && mi <= 12) {
          d = Date.newInstance(d.year(),mi,d.day());
        }
   }
   // and year as yr=2008
   if (y_param != null) { 
        Integer yr = Integer.valueOf(y_param); 
        d = Date.newInstance(yr, d.month(), d.day());
   }

   setMonth(d);
  }

  public List<Month.Week> getWeeks() { 
    system.assert(month!=null,'month is null');
    return month.getWeeks();
  }

  public Month getMonth() { return month; } 


  private void setMonth(Date d) { 
    month = new Month(d);  
    system.assert(month != null); 

    Date[] da = month.getValidDateRange();  // gather events that fall in this month
    events = [ select id,subject,description,activitydate,activitydatetime,DurationInMinutes,Location,Owner.Name
        from Event 
        where activitydate >= :da[0] AND activityDate <= :da[1]
        order by activitydatetime];

    month.setEvents(events);  // merge those events into the month class
  }

  public void addMonth(Integer val) { 
    Date d = month.getFirstDate();
    d = d.addMonths(val);
    setMonth(d);
  }

  private List<Event> events;
  private Month month;
}
```

Comment: Please link your attribution to Ross so we can follow you more easily.

Comment: Of course. His thread on the code share is [link] http://developer.force.com/codeshare/projectpage?id=a0630000002ahp6AAA

Comment: The suspect line in `setEvents` appears to be `c.eventsToday.add(new EventItem(e));`. Likely either the Day `c` or its member `eventsToday` are null. Try adding some logging or TracePoints to check what is going on in that method.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was All Day events. Added isAllDayEvent to the select line, then added an if statement.

Thanks for the comments.